# Who was in the Romulus system first - Romulans or Remans?

Tags: star-trek, romulan

We know that Romulan heritage goes back to Vulcan, so the Romulans weren't native to Romulus. But where does their arrival fit on the Reman evolution timeline?  So **which species was in the Romulus system first?  The Remans or the Romulans?**

Canon sources preferred please, but no longer required.

Comment: The only canon appearance/reference to the Remans is in Nemesis, and their history is never explained. If you're truly only interested in canon sources then your question is unanswerable. For the record, non-canon sources claim that the Remans are an evolutionary offshoot of the Romulans.

Comment: @ApproachingDarknessFish thanks for your contribution. I will leave my canon only request for a day and then take it down. The reason I included it was in the hope someone might find a reference in a screen guide or something like that for Nemesis

Comment: The novelisation has an interesting frontispiece; *"The idea of the Remans being vampirelike slaves, laboring away in the dilithium mines, never seeing the sun, grew out of our desire to create a truly monstrous race. **It seemed obvious to me that the Romulans would subjugate some other race to dig dilithium for them**. Much too messy for our pristine and elegant Romulans"* - But unfortunately it doesn't confirm whether the Remans were found in-system or imported.

Comment: @Valorum but nonetheless interesting!

Comment: @ApproachingDarknessFish The Remans also appear in the ENT episode "The Aenar" (http://memory-alpha.wikia.com/wiki/The_Aenar_(episode)), although I don't believed they are ever named as such.

Comment: @ApproachingDarknessFish I've lifted the restriction now

Comment: Don't forget the Roman origin myth that has Rome being founded by the twin brothers Romulus and Remus. Out of universe, the choice of the name Remans to go with Romulans was clearly meant to suggest a parallel.

Comment: The Romulans are descendents of Vulcans who rejected Surak's teachings. In 'Enterprise' it's established that Surak lived/died some 1800 years earlier, so in our 4th century. In 'Enterprise' we also see fully recognisable Remans. 1800 Years are not enough to achieve this kind of evolutionary drift, so Remans are a separate species. Seeing how many humanoid species there are in the Star Trek universe, it is *likely* the Remans are native to Remus and so they *probably* were there first.

Comment: @OftenRight : Have some time on my hands, and so going through my recent answers.  Anything else required below?  :-)

Comment: @Praxis just my acceptance!  Sorry I had quite forgotten about accepting this!

Comment: @OftenRight : No worries!  And thanks! :-)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

## The Remans are the indigenous population of Remus

According to the **database on the official Star Trek web site**, the Remans are the native population of Remus:

> Humanoid, light-sensitive ***native species*** of Remus, the sister planet to Romulus, who evolved in their world's dark-side hemisphere and have largely remained subjugated by their more powerful neighbors.

([Source — "Remans" Database Entry](http://www.startrek.com/database_article/remans))

In other words, the Remans were not an imported vassal / slave species.  They were already in the system and the arriving Romulans eventually enslaved them.

Comment: What about the story in the novel: vulcan souls?